# How to setup slaves in mpi in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, openssh, mpich

I am following the following link to setup a cluster. But I am facing an issue with ssh into another machine.

link 1 :
http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/

link 2 : 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster

Currently I am in :

> vagrant@vagrant:~$

When I create a mpiuser, and run su -mpiuser, it becomes

> mpiuser@vagrant:~$

How to change it to (as show in link 2)

> mpiuser@ub0:~$

Answer (score 0):

"mpiuser@ub0:~$" means that you have logged into the node "ub0" as "mpiuser".
so you can use the ssh to do it
ssh mpiuser@ub0
Regards